# MapActivity, how to add a progress bar in the marker popup?

Tags: java, android, maps

I'm using MapActivity and I would like to put a progress bar in the marker popup that appears by clicking on it. I would like to put it under the marker title, in the area where the snippet would have been.

the marker I use is declared as it follows

```
new MarkerOptions().position(infoLocal.getUserLocation()).title("Your Location").snippet("This is you!").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.player3)).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
```

Comment: Post your tries

Comment: Are you using google maps?

Comment: @AndroidUser I don't know how to do it and if it is possible to do it, now I use simple markers with a title and a snippet.

Comment: @Raj yes I'm using MapActivity

Comment: Can you specify which map are you using like google maps, mapbox ,etc.

Comment: @Raj I'm using the default Google Map activity from android studio presets. Google Maps Android API v2

Comment: you can only add `BitmapDescriptor` in marker icon ... otherwise you can add a view above `mapFragment` to show circular prograssbar

As Uber and Careem did this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Android docs:
'An info window is not a live View. Instead, the view is rendered as an image on the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.'

Hence you can not put live components (like progress bar) in a info window, As it converts the whole view to an image.

If you still want to achieve this, this library may help:
https://github.com/Appolica/InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! I'm having some troubles adding the library to my project, I have tried with a guide but I'm getting errors with the build. Can you help me? thanks in advance

Comment: I get gradle build failed error, which method should I use to add the project as a library?